# Call as(...,"transactions") from the arules package inside another package

Tags: r, apriori

I develop an R package which requires some `arules` functions.
I'm able to use them with

`LinkingTo: arules 
 Imports: arules`

in the DESCRIPTION file of my package, and by prefixing them with `arules::`

However I'm stuck while trying to convert a `.csv` file into a `transactions` object using the `as(...,"transactions")` function with this error message :

`Error in as(data, "transactions") : 
  no method or default for coercing “data.frame” to “transactions”`

I have the desired result when `library(arules)` is called in my R session but this error using my package only. How to use it in my package properly ?

My goal is to get all the labels of my dataset, so the solution I've implemented is :

`data = read.csv(...)")
 t = as(data, "transactions")
 return( t@itemInfo$labels )`

For instance, with the mtcars dataset sample , it returns `[1] "mpg=10.4"   "mpg=13.3"   "mpg=14.3"   "mpg=14.7"   "mpg=15"     "mpg=15.2" ...`

Maybe there is also another way to achieve the same result ?